# Creating a process work flow graph with graphviz from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, graphviz

I have the following information in a pandas dataframe

```
Source  Target
0   u5  u2
1   u7  u5
2   u7  u7
3   u5  u7
4   u3  u5
5   u2  u3
6   u7  u1
7   u7  u7
8   u5  u7
9   u6  u5
10  u4  u6
11  u2  u4
12  u8  u2
13  u8  u8
14  u5  u8
15  u5  u5
16  u3  u5
17  u2  u3
18  u8  u1
19  u7  u8
```

I have been trying to create a process flow graph with graphviz.

Here's what I have tried so far

```
E = graphviz.Digraph()
for index, row in graphviztest2.iterrows():
    E.edge(row['Source'], row['Target'], label='')
E
```

But it is not giving me the process flow graph.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you mention the error or output you're getting when you run this?

Comment: Thanks @VishalRao I have solved the issue now. However, I have another question. Is there a way I can add a Start and Stop node to a graphviz graph and link them to data from a pandas dataframe?